# Tab widget example not running

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I'm trying to reproduce the tabwidget example (http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html). I'm not really sure what's the problem, I got no errors while compiling, but i cannot see the application on the emulators screen.

It would be excellent if maybe anyone could have a look at my classes and tell me what's my mistake? I've packed my project here: http://etanto.com/TabTest.zip

### here's the console dump while the run:

```
[2010-06-10 09:18:34 - TabTest] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Virtual1'
[2010-06-10 09:18:35 - TabTest] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2010-06-10 09:18:35 - TabTest] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2010-06-10 09:19:05 - TabTest] WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement!
[2010-06-10 09:19:05 - TabTest] Device API version is 8 (Android 2.2)
[2010-06-10 09:19:05 - TabTest] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2010-06-10 09:19:05 - TabTest] Uploading TabTest.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2010-06-10 09:19:05 - TabTest] Installing TabTest.apk...
[2010-06-10 09:19:22 - TabTest] Success!
[2010-06-10 09:19:22 - TabTest] \TabTest\bin\TabTest.apk installed on device
[2010-06-10 09:19:22 - TabTest] Done!
```

---

Comment: Is there happening anything on the emulator? The screen going black? A popup window saying that your app is closed?  

You should try to use logcat to get the error log of the device maybe there is something shown. 
The last thing is that your console does not look like your app is starting. Are you using eclipse to start the program or the console? How do you start your app on the emulator?

Comment: nothing happens in the emulator (and no popups or errors). i'm using eclipse to start the program. there must be an error inside my files i thing, because the hello world example is running and starts in emulator without problems..
[2010-06-10 09:52:45 - HelloWorld] Installing HelloWorld.apk...
[2010-06-10 09:53:01 - HelloWorld] Success!
[2010-06-10 09:53:01 - HelloWorld] Starting activity on device 
[2010-06-10 09:53:05 - HelloWorld] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.etanto.helloworld/.HelloWorld }

Answer (score 2):

try to add the following to your manifest:

```
<activity ......>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

This will declare the activity as "main" activity if app is started...

Otherwise you could try to specify an api level in your manifest.

I didn't read all the code, but if there are no compilation problems, the activity should be started anyway(if manifest is ok)...

Comment: ok great, one step ahead. with the changed manifest i'm getting now an popup on simulator which says: the app TabTest (process com.etanot.tabtest) has stopped unexpectedly. please try again

obviously i have another problem in my classes which i do not see...compiling has no errors, i've got no idea :(

Comment: alright, I see another thing...in you <activity android:name="..." ...> you have to declare your class in given package like android:name=".TabTest"

Comment: oh you're right, lost the dot while my last change. manifest should be right now, but the error is still the same..i do not undestand whats the problem :((

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
   <activity android:name=".TabTest" android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

Comment: can you just upload your current project again, please?

Comment: http://www.etanto.com/TabTest2.zip

thank you very much for your help, awesome :-)

Comment: Hi, at first glance I don't see an error...can you please post, what logcat says?

Comment: here's what logcat says:
06-10 10:12:44.134: WARN/ActivityManager(59): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{43e8f718 com.gamestar.tabtest/.TabTest}
06-10 10:12:49.225: DEBUG/dalvikvm(115): GC_EXPLICIT freed 779 objects / 42704 bytes in 87ms
06-10 10:13:05.838: DEBUG/SntpClient(59): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol

Comment: ah, you also have to declare every activity in your manifest like this:

<activity android:name=".SongsActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
  </activity>

Comment: hallelujah, it works :-)
thank you so much and sorry for the mess, have a nice day

michbeck